# PowerMod solve for b (exponent)

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Using `PowerMod[a, b, m] = x`  I get

```
PowerMod[7083743828014719382182429498318732567101865686, 
16793129237622992703097532489897447320171386, 
46935289616461321113779007835893780311135345411] = 27698423133730310633419581544937507947750677054
```

However, if I only know

```
a = 7083743828014719382182429498318732567101865686
m = 46935289616461321113779007835893780311135345411
x = 27698423133730310633419581544937507947750677054
```

How can I solve for $b$?

Comment: Might be `MultiplicativeOrder[a, m, {x}]` but this can be slow...

Comment: Is that working for you? Unfortunately, it don't work for me.